# Transition not working on my accordion in Nuxt

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an accordion of brands that opens and closes, the problem is that the animation for it to close and open in `0.5` seconds doesn't work.

The code is shown below

below is my template for the animation

```html
<template>
  <div class="brands">
    <p class="brands-title">SOME OF OUR CLIENTS AND FRIENDS</p>
    <div class="brands-logos" :class="{ 'open-clients': closedClients }">
      <img v-for="(brand, index) in clients" :key="index" :src="require(`@/assets/brands/${brand.src}`)" :alt="brand.src">
    </div>
    <div class="brand-center">
      <button @click.prevent="closedClients=!closedClients">
        {{ closedClients ? 'View All Clients' : 'View Less Clients' }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

below is the script

```js
data() {
  return {
    clients: [
      {src: 'arts.png', link: '/blog/'},
      {src: 'kingsCollege.png', link: '/blog/'},
      {src: 'kpmg.png', link: '/blog/'},
      {src: 'mandc.png', link: '/blog/'},
      {src: 'nhs.png', link: '/blog/'},
      {src: 'starbucks.png', link: '/blog/'},
      {src: 'uber.png', link: '/blog/'}
    ],
    closedClients: true
  }
},
```

and finally the CSS

```css
.brands {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}

.brands-title {
  color: #002047;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.brands-logos {
  height: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 70px;
  transition: height .5s;
}

.brands-logos img {
  max-width: 210px;
  max-height: 92px;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

.brand-center button {
  color: #fff;
  background: #002047;
  padding: 22px 43px;
}

.open-clients {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

the `brands-logos` is where the animation is specified and how long it should run.

and the `open-clients` class is what is attached for the expanding and closing of the accordion.

and even though the mobile version code isn't here, the only time I notice an animation is when I change screens on resizing.

Comment: `height: cover` is not a [valid value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) apparently. Never saw this one and it's not in the docs. The error is probably coming from here.

Comment: @kissu that explains a lot, thank you

Comment: Did you achieved to fix your error?

Comment: yeah your comment gave me an idea, I changed `height: auto` it didn't work as I noticed that for the animation to work you need a specified height, so I eventually used `max-height` and gave the expanded value a large number, and it works well now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `height` to something that does exist `auto` for example and adding a `max-height` fixed the issue here!